# Automatic hibernation of application instance on cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I have a cloudbees enterprise instance that I use for performance and automated UI testing.

The free instance (which is limited in memory) cannot support the memory or request per second that we have for testing.

I would like to have the instance automatically hibernated when I am not using it but have it wake up when requests come in.  I would configure a jenkins job to wake the app up (by issuing a request) before kicking off my sauce lab based selenium jobs.

My question is how do I configure automatic hibernation?  The control panel has minimum of one instance which I guess means that the one instance stays up.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - currently automatic hibernation is only for free applications. When an application is hibernated (vs stopped) then it will be automatically woken whenever someone needs to access it.

What you could do for this is to have a job set your application to hibernated, say once a day, (or at certain time of the day when you know it won't be needed). When it is needed again - you won't need to do anything - simply accessing it will cause it to be activated (woken) again - so your test script can just insure that is the case (and ideally, after a test run, set it to hibernated again).

It really depends how often the app is needed - if you can work out what points it isn't needed and trigger the hibernate off that (eg after a test run) then that is ideal (you minimise cost).

Comment: Michael, I see that the API call to hibernate an app is not available in the REST API: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/API But it is available in the CLI SDK: https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK

Is it possible to access the CloudBees SDK from within Jenkins?

Comment: Yes it is possible to use the SDK from within jenkins.

Comment: Also, the bees api client has hibernate added to it:

Comment: I had tried earlier to do this but no luck: https://lsi.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Jenkins%20job%20hibernation/3/console

Comment: Michael, I'm also searching on CloudBees API for hibernate and don't see it: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/API

Comment: Ok, I see the method applicationHibernate on the latest GitHub commit: https://github.com/cloudbees/cloudbees-api-client/blob/master/cloudbees-api-client/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/api/BeesClient.java

However, it is not in the 1.3 version of the BeesClient that I have from maven repo nor is there any mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: yes it is only new - and was for the command line interface, so hasn't been documented properly yet, but if you grab the source you can use it - or "reverse engineer" it